# AttributeError 'UserViewset' object has no attribute 'action'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I've been using the Django rest framework, and I'm trying to customize the get_parsers method in my UserViewset, I looked at the docs and found a similar use case with permission classes in [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#introspecting-viewset-actions), and I tried to customize the get_parsers like this

```
class UserViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
serializer_class = UserSerializer

# Redefine get_parsers, so that only the update methods have form-data media type
def get_parsers(self):
    if self.action == 'update' or self.action == 'partial_update':
        parser_classes = [FormParser, MultiPartParser]
    else:
        parser_classes = [JSONParser]
    return [parser() for parser in parser_classes]
```

but I keep getting the error: `AttributeError at /api/auth/users/: 'UserViewset' object has no attribute 'action'`
I tried the use case found in the docs and it worked perfectly.
What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: During the `.initiall_request`, this method is triggered, and at that moment the `.action` attribute is not *yet* set.

Comment: So I can't use it, and i have to separate the views ?

Comment: Maybe try to override `initial_request` (call super first), and then modify the returned request's parser?

Comment: okay, i'll try to

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, thanks to fb.com/laidani.basset @bdbd and @willem-van-onsem and u/vikingvynotking, I've been able to fix it with 2 different solutions:

- The first is to override initialize_request like this, the idea is to set the request parsers to the instance of which parser you want; the drop back is when you're using swagger or any API doc, it'll not differentiate between the method parsers and it'll be just one parser, in my case it's JSONParser:

  ```
   def initialize_request(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

       request = super().initialize_request(request, *args, **kwargs)
       print(request.method)
       if request.method in ['PUT', 'PATCH']:
           request.parsers = [FormParser(), MultiPartParser()]
       else:
           request.parsers = [JSONParser()]

       self.action = self.action_map.get(request.method.lower())
       return request
  ```
- The second solution is to override initialize_request so that the self.action is called before calling the request, and then use the get_parsers method as you like, in this case, the swagger will differentiate between the parsers of each method:

  ```
   def initialize_request(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       self.action = self.action_map.get(request.method.lower())
       return super().initialize_request(request, *args, **kwargs)
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You should cast your viewset to .as_view() for example;

```
path('users/', UserViewset.as_view(), name='users'),
```

Comment: I'm registring it using rest_frameworks routres like this 
from rest_framework import routers

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('users', UserViewset)